# RStudio + Knitr + mind mapping

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, tikz

I am trying to integrate mind mapping using tikz library into rstudio code.
But am getting an error:

improper  \prevdepth

missing \endgroup inserted.

Here is the piece of code.

```
  % mind mapping packages.

   \usepackage{tikz}

   \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

   \usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic, text width = 3cm, align=flush center, ]

\node{Data }

      child{node{Renaming Data Variable}}

      child{node{Converting data types}}

      child{node{Working with date format}}

      child{node{Adding New Records}}

      child{node{Filtering Data}}

      child{node{Dropping Data}}

      child{node{Merging and sorting data}}

      child{node{Reshaping Data}}

      child{node{Detecting Messy Data}}

      child{node{{Imputing Missing Data}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please check your post and properly format your code. At the moment your question does not contain valid TikZ/mindmap syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your post does not contain valid TikZ/mindmap code, here is a reproducible example based on code examples found on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/mindmaps/).

### RMarkdown code

Here the critical part is to include additional LaTeX packages and header directives under `header-includes` in the YAML header of the RMarkdown document.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{tikz}
   - \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
output: pdf_document
---

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {Computer Science}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept color=green!50!black] {
      node[concept] {practical}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node[concept] {algorithms} }
      child { node[concept] {data structures} }
      child { node[concept] {pro\-gramming languages} }
      child { node[concept] {software engineer\-ing} }
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {applied}
      [clockwise from=-30]
      child { node[concept] {databases} }
      child { node[concept] {WWW} }
    }
    child[concept color=red] { node[concept] {technical} }
    child[concept color=orange] { node[concept] {theoretical} };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Screenshot of output

[image]

Comment: Hello Maurits Evers, thank you very much. I have used  test.Rnw file extensions. Let me try this and see what happens.

Comment: suppose I have 10 primary concept, like practical , applied, technical, etc. They have secondary concept, may be three for each.  I divided 360/10 to get the angle between the siblings. However, the mind map is no clear. Probably is the distance between the sibling?

Comment: the code has a lot of line cant post here?. Any suggestion?.

Comment: This seems more of a conceptual issue with mindmap than an R/knitr/RMarkdown specific coding problem. I’m not sure whether SO is the right place for this kind of question. I’ve got no experience with mindmap so unfortunately won’t be able to help. In any case you should probably ask a new question. Provide clear sample data and a mock-up of your expected output.